# Enumerate when adding variables with same key to array?

Tags: bash

This must very simple but I cannot figure this out. I tried looking at the GNU docs and looked for similar answers on stack I cannot find anything.

I have a loop that copies a bunch of files and after each copy I check the exit code to see if it was successful or not and set a variable based on that. `Copy=OK` or `Copy=failed`

I want to add each result to an array so I can later on check if any files copies failed so I end up with something like `copy[0]=OK copy[1]=failed` so I can do a search on failed copies.

The closest I got is this but this just saves OK and failed once.

```
declare -A TEST

copy=OK
TEST[$copy]=$copy
copy=OK
TEST[$copy]=$copy
copy=OK
TEST[$copy]=$copy
copy=failed
TEST[$copy]=$copy

echo ${TEST[*]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much cleaner to keep 2 separate array for success and failures. Here a a pseudo code:

```
# initialize arrays
ok=()
fail=()

while file in *.txt do;
    # run copy command
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
       ok+=("$file")
    else
       fail+=("$file")
    fi
done

# print success cases
printf '%s\n' "${ok[@]}"

# print failure cases
printf '%s\n' "${fail[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple indexed array and append it like this

```
test=()

test+=("$copy")
echo "${test[@]}"
```